# Easier to manage dataflow with webforms or mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a database and I want to allow users that I give permission, the ability to place data into database using asp.net.

I want to pay for leads through co-reg agreements and then allow after registration to post to database through url.

I then do some work to check for dupes before I do another post to a different site.

The website will then receive a postback from the site before making its second and final post to another different url.

I have never tried anything like this. How would I go about setting this up with visual studio 2010. I know it can be done, I am just looking for the path of least resistance.

Would it be easier to do this using webforms or mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your experience. If you've used neither, it's probably worth going with MVC, as it's generally nicer, and works as the web works (as opposed to WebForms which tries to work like a Windows program). There are loads of resources for getting started with ASP.NET MVC, and here's a good a place as any: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc-part1. It should give you some ideas to get going.

Comment: I have gone through the necessary tutorials with mvc to be able to do this. I think I will just go with MVC and post questions then.

Comment: Good idea. Once you've done a couple of actions and see how it works it gets much easier. Good luck!